# Checking a dictionary if there are same values for a key

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary object like this:

```
CustomKeys<int, string>
```

eg;

```
1000, F1
1001, F2
1002, F1
1003, F4
1004, F2
```

I want to know if I have more than 1 of same values in this dictionary. I would also want to keep a note of which keys(unique id) has duplicates.

Is that possible?

Comment: `Keys<int, string>`, what is that? Is `Keys` some custom type of yours?

Comment: Do you want to keep a running list of the duplicates as the dictionary is modified, or just a one-time snapshot?

Comment: How big will the size of your dictionary be?

Comment: MatthewJ size is not an issue in regards to the OP's question

Answer (score 4):

It is possible using `GroupBy` and than `Count() > 1` to keep track of which values that have duplicates.

```
var q = dic.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
        .Select (x => new { Item = x, HasDuplicates = x.Count() > 1 });
```

Comment: Did you mean `Item = x.Key`?

Answer (score 3):

You can find all key values they had the same values like this;

```
    Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    d.Add(1000, "F1");
    d.Add(1001, "F2");
    d.Add(1002, "F1");
    d.Add(1003, "F4");
    d.Add(1004, "F2");

    var dublicate = d.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);

    foreach (var i in dublicate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.Key);
    }
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/qNtvcB).

But if you want to get a `boolean` value since your item's has a same value, look at [Magnus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444979/447156) which is great.

Comment: I was expecting a LINQ based answer with Lambdas :) and here it is! +1

Comment: This is useful if you want to compute the duplicates once. But the question says “I […] want to keep a note …” and I think that means the list of duplicates should be available always, without a complicated operation to create it every time you want to use it.

Comment: @svick Yeah, I little bit misunderstood the question because the question is not good explained unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure by what you mean by "keeping note of which has duplicate values". If you mean keeping note of the keys, you could do this:

```
        var keys = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        keys.Add(1000, "F1");
        keys.Add(1001, "F2");
        keys.Add(1002, "F1");
        keys.Add(1003, "F4");
        keys.Add(1004, "F2");

        var duplicates = keys.GroupBy(i => i.Value).Select(i => new
        {
            keys = i.Select(x => x.Key),
            value = i.Key,
            count = i.Count()
        });

        foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0} Count: {1}", duplicate.value, duplicate.count);
            foreach (var key in duplicate.keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - {0}", key);
            }
        }
```

If you mean keeping track of the duplicate values only, see Sonor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be:

```
var duplicates = dictionary.GroupBy( g => g.Value )
                           .Where( x => x.Count( ) > 1 )
                           .Select( x => new { Item = x.First( ), Count = x.Count( ) } )
                           .ToList( );
```